# How to configure route53 and cloudfront for EC2 website

Tags: amazon-cloudfront, amazon-route53

My website `abc.domain.com` is hosted on EC2.

In cloudfront I put `abc.domain.com` in the  “Origin Domain Name” field and the "Alternate Domain Names (CNAMEs)" field.

Origin Domain Name: `abc.domain.com`

Alternate Domain Names (CNAMEs): `abc.domain.com`

The “Domain Name” of this distribution is `xxx.cloudfront.net`. In route53 I setup ALIAS A record with `abc.domain.com` point to `xxx.cloudfront.net.`

The problem is that with  `abc.domain.com` point to `xxx.cloudfront.net`, route53 will not allow me to make another A record with `abc.domain.com` point to the IP of this EC2 so the "Origin Domain Name: `abc.domain.com`" will not work.

========================== Possible Solution =====================

Origin Domain Name: `abc2.domain.com`

Alternate Domain Names (CNAMEs): `abc.domain.com`

In route53 Setup ALIAS A record with `abc.domain.com` point to `xxx.cloudfront.net`.

In route53 make `abc2.domain.com` point to the IP of this EC2 so the "Origin Domain Name: `abc2.domain.com`" will work.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers Help by voting and accepting answer if its works

Answer (score 2):

If you have to use CloudFront+ EC2+ Route53 for domain abc.domain.com then you required below :

1. Create ELB( Elastic load balancing ) with EC2
2. Then you map your CloudFront to ELB point.
3. In Route53 mappend your CloudFront.

Step which you following is will not allow you to create duplicate record entry. This is mandatory to use ELB if you want to use CloudFront with EC2.

If you dont want to use ELB then another option is purchase SSL certificate from external vendor and install it in EC2. Then you can directly point EC2 Ip to Route53. In this you don't require CloudFront.

Ask if you have any doubt.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I think ELB will cost money so I come up with a possible solution by creating another domain name `abc2.domain.com`. I am not sure if this is the right solution. Please see the edit above.

Comment: why you required abc2.domain.com ? ELB will be costlier always.

Comment: I wish to find a solution without paying money. The solution I found requires `abc2.domain.com`. But I am not sure if this solution is a good one. Although it works. Thanks.